# Jquery Form Validation Difficulty

Tags: jquery, html, validation

New developer here.  I'm trying to validate a couple forms with jquery but I can't seem to get it to work.  The page does not react when the "submit" button is pressed.  If anybody knows why this following code doesn't work I would really appreciate it:

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/programmersujeet/7YDxd/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        firstname: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true
        },
        lastname: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true
        }
    },
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Login</h3>

<form>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="firstname">First Name:</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="firstname" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastname" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by, 'doesn't work'? What errors are you seeing? What behaviour is ensuing?

Comment: The page does not react when the submit button is pressed.  I can see I was pretty unclear about that, I'll edit my original post to include that information.

Comment: Where is your open form tag? I can see the close form...

Comment: @EngineerDollery — Immediately after the `<h3>Login</h3>`

Comment: You're binding to the `form` before it is constructed. Try placing the `script` block AFTER your body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Tested and working!

***1.*** You forgot to include `jquery.validate.js` plugin to your current *jsFiddle / HTML* in order to use `$('form').validate(..)`, you can add it from the official *CDN*:

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/jquery.validate.min.js *(You can download it also from: http://jqueryvalidation.org - download section).*

Please don't forget to check browser `console` since `error` was evident:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'validate'

---

***2.*** For the ones who tell you to use `<input type="submit" />` and since you're using  *bootstrap* (I know it because you imported *bootstrap.min.js* and *bootstrap.min.css* in your current *jsFiddle*). It is recommended to use `<button>` tag ***whenever possible to ensure matching Cross-browser rendering***. Please read: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-tags and leave your *HTML* as it is.

---

Your *jsFiddle* is working now, take a look.

***Live Demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/vck4F/

Answer (score 0):

Your form's submit should be an `<input>` element, rather than a `<button>` element.

See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp